# Windows Batch File Time Comparison

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to compare current system time to a set time. Please see below:

```
 set currentTime=%TIME%
 set flag=false

 if %currentTime% geq 07:00 if %currentTime% leq 22:45 set flag=true

 if %flag%==true (


 ) else (

 )
```

If the time is between 7 am and 10:45pm then perform this action otherwise perform the other.

The problem is this doesn't work.  The results constantly vary. I think it has to do with my comparison to i.e., 07:00

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason your script is failing is for time before 10 AM.  When the time is less than 10, the %Time% variable returns this format: `" H:MM:SS:ss"`.  However when 10 or later the `%Time%` variable returns this format: `"HH:MM:SS:ss"`.

Note the missing `0` at the beggining of the times before `10` is missing.  This causes a comparison issue since batch is doing a string comparison and not a numeric comparison.

`07:00` is less than `6:00` due to the fact that the ASCII value of `6` is greater than the ASCII value of `0`.

The solution requires that you append a zero to the beginning of the time if it is before 10AM.

**Just change**

```
set currentTime=%TIME%
```

**Into**

```
set "currentTime=%Time: =0%"
```

This will replace any spaces in the time with zeros.