# A batch job which would copy/delete text files created in the past 5 days

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am working on creating a simple batch job which would copy and then delete text files from one specified directory to another. However, I am trying to only copy/delete files created in the past 5 days. Can days be specified using the MOVE batch command?

Here is what I have so far. This script deletes the files from the original directory and copy them to the new directory.

```
@echo off
C:
cd C:\Air
move c:\Air\*.txt d:\Air_backup
cd C:\
exit
```

Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: @Haitham Salah: You can use 'dir /T:C' to get file creation date and time. By comparing them with the current %DATE% and %TIME% ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282788/windows-batch-file-time-comparison)) you will get desired time span. At the end the script would test if 5 days have passed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you'd call simple, but it will delete files older than 5 minutes (using creation date) from the current folder.

At the moment the del command will only be echoed to the screen so remove the `echo` keyword after the `if %MinsOld% gtr 5` to enable the del command and **change the 5 to 7200** for `7200` minutes.

**XP users will have problems with some filenames occasionally due to a short filename bug in Windows XP.**

The code can use CreationDate or LastModified

Change this line:

```
if %MinsOld% gtr 5 echo del "%~1"
```

to this to move the 5 day old files to a target folder:

```
if %MinsOld% gtr 7200 move "%~1" "d:\target\folder"
```

Here is the essential code:

```
@echo off
if /i not "%~1"=="debug" set debug=::
:: Wmic removes regional differences
:: XP Pro can have some filename errors due to the short filename bug

setlocal

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "stamp=%YYYY% %MM% %DD% %HH% %Min%"

%debug% echo current time "%stamp%"

call :DateToMinutes %stamp% NowMins

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir * /a-d /b ^|find /v /i "%~nx0"') do call :CheckMins "%%~fa"
pause
goto :EOF

:CheckMins
set "filestamp="
set "filemins="
set "MinsOld="
set "YY=" & set "YYYY=" & set "MM=" & set "DD="
set "HH=" & set "Min=" & set "Sec=" & set "dt="
set "file=%~sf1"

:: can use CreationDate instead of lastmodified

WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="%file:\=\\%" get creationdate | find "." >file.tmp
for /f %%a in (file.tmp) do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "filestamp=%YYYY% %MM% %DD% %HH% %Min%"
del file.tmp 2>nul

%debug% echo file time    "%filestamp%"


if not defined yyyy goto :EOF

call :DateToMinutes %filestamp% FileMins

set /a MinsOld=%NowMins%-%FileMins%
%debug% echo Now:%NowMins% File:%FileMins% Fileage:%minsold% "%~1"
%debug% pause
if %MinsOld% gtr 5 echo del "%~1"
goto :EOF

:DateToMinutes
setlocal
set yy=%1&set mm=%2&set dd=%3&set hh=%4&set nn=%5
if 1%yy% LSS 200 if 1%yy% LSS 170 (set yy=20%yy%) else (set yy=19%yy%)
set /a dd=100%dd%%%100,mm=100%mm%%%100
set /a z=14-mm,z/=12,y=yy+4800-z,m=mm+12*z-3,j=153*m+2
set /a j=j/5+dd+y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-2472633
if 1%hh% LSS 20 set hh=0%hh%
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {p} if "%hh%" NEQ "12" set hh=1%hh%&set/a hh-=88
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {a} if "%hh%" EQU "12" set hh=00
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} GEQ {a} set nn=%nn:~0,2%
set /a hh=100%hh%%%100,nn=100%nn%%%100,j=j*1440+hh*60+nn
endlocal&set %6=%j%&goto :EOF
```